# Wrong output when using csv file

Tags: java

so I am doing this assignment and after finishing it one part of the Code isn't executing properly.

**Warehouse**

```
class Warehouse {
    private final Merchandise[] merchandise;

    Warehouse(Merchandise[] merchandise) {
        this.merchandise = merchandise;
    }

    public static Warehouse fromCsv(String file) {
        In.open(file);
        String material = In.readFile();
        In.close();

        String lines[] = material.split("\n");
        Merchandise[] merchandise = new Merchandise[lines.length];
        for(int i=0; i<merchandise.length; i++) {
            String[] parts = lines[i].split(",");


        Article article = null;
        if(parts[0].equals("instrument")) {
            article = new Instrument(parts[1],Double.parseDouble(parts[2]),parts[3],Integer.parseInt(parts[4]));
        }else{
            article = new Accessory(parts[1],Double.parseDouble(parts[2]),parts[3],parts[4]);
        }
        merchandise[i] = new Merchandise(article,Integer.parseInt(parts[5]));
        }
        return new Warehouse(merchandise);
    }

    public Merchandise[] getMerchandise() {
        return merchandise.clone();
    }

    public Merchandise findMerchandise(String name) {
        Merchandise found = null;
        for(Merchandise the : merchandise) {
            if(the.getArticle().getName().equals(name)) {
                found = the;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

**Shop**

```
class Shop {
    private final Warehouse warehouse;

    Shop(Warehouse warehouse){
        this.warehouse = warehouse;
    }

    public void printCatalog() {
        Out.println();
        Out.formatln("%-30s%20s%10s", "Name" , "Price","Quantity");
        String format = "%-30s%20.2f%10d"; 
        for(Merchandise the : warehouse.getMerchandise()) {
         Out.formatln(format,the.getArticle().getName(),the.getArticle().getPrice(),the.getQuantity());
         }  
    } 

    public void printProductDescription(String name){
        Merchandise merchandise = warehouse.findMerchandise(name);

        Out.println();
        if(merchandise != null) {
            Out.println(merchandise);
        }else {
            Out.println("The article does not exist");
            Out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Warehouse warehouse = Warehouse.fromCsv("warehouse.csv");
        Shop shop = new Shop(warehouse);

        while(true) {
            Out.println("Pianos & more");
            Out.println("0. Print Catalogue");
            Out.println("1. Search Article");
            Out.println();
            Out.print("Selection:");
            int selection = In.readInt();
            In.read();


            switch(selection) {
                case 0:
                shop.printCatalog();
                break;
                case 1:
                Out.print("Article name:");
                String name = In.readLine();
                shop.printProductDescription(name);
                break;
                default:
                Out.println("Invalid selection");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the part where I print out the catalog is working fine, but when I try to search an article it takes the Article name, and just prints out "article doesn't exist" although it should. Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add some unit tests and you will probably discover where it goes wrong.

Comment: Okay, this might be a stupid question but what are unit tests and how do I add them? Im very new to Java, I've never heard of that sorry.

Comment: I don't know what `In.readLine()` is, but is it possible that it returns a string with a trailing newline?  (I.e. you type in `article 1` but the value read into the variable `name` is `article 1\n`?)

Comment: Hmm okay, well if that is the case (and I'm not sure that it is) what other way of reading the input should i use?

Comment: I have no idea what your `In` class is: whether it's something you've written or something that you have to use for your assignment.  If you are getting blank space on the end of `name`, use the `trim()` method to get rid of it, using `if (name != null) { name = name.trim(); }`.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try

Comment: Unit tests are small tests, that test a single class, or two or three classes that work together. By making sure, these small tests will make sure each small thing in the classes do functionally what they are supposed to do. Read the following tutorial https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html and you will get a better idea.